# Error fetching remote repo 'origin' while checkout a project using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Error fetching remote repo 'origin' while checkout a project using Jenkins. Project can be checkout using "git clone" command in the command prompt. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you post error logs?

Comment: FATAL: Could not checkout f6b72efd11d41eb98bb761186666e15a0c1cfe28
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git checkout -f f6b72efd11d41eb98bb761186666e15a0c1cfe28" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: error: unable to create file Resources/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0-java/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPDataCallback.java: Filename too long

Comment: fatal: cannot create directory at 'Resources/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-5.0.3-java/vendor/jar-dependencies/org/logstash/filters/logstash-filter-geoip/4.2.0': Filename too long

Comment: fatal: cannot create directory at 'Resources/logstash/logstash-6.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-5.0.3-java/vendor/jar-dependencies/org/logstash/filters/logstash-filter-geoip/4.2.0': Filename too long

 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2430)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$1100(CliGitAPIImpl.java:81)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2743)

Comment: Caused: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout f6b72efd11d41eb98bb761186666e15a0c1cfe28
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$9.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2767)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1217)
 at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:504)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1208)

Comment: at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:574)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:499)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1818)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: something is not configured correctly in the scm checkout, have you tried cloning the repository from your local to see if it works? Please attach a screenshot of scm checkout in Jenkins job